# Speeding up TFRecords feed into Keras model on CloudML for GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml

I would like to feed TFRecords into my model at a super fast rate. However, currently, my GPU(Single K80 on GCP) is at 0% load which is super slow on *CloudML*.

I have TFRecords in GCS: `train_directory = gs://bucket/train/*.tfrecord`,  (around 100 files of 30mb-800mb in size), but for some reason it struggles to feed the data into my model fast enough for GPU.

Interestingly, loading data into memory and using numpy arrays using `fit_generator()` is 7x faster. There I can specify multi-processing and multi workers.

My current set up parses tf records and loads an infinite `tf.Dataset`. Ideally, the solution would save/prefecth some batches in memory, for the gpu to use on demand.

```
def _parse_func(record):
    """ Parses TF Record"""
    keys_to_features = {}
    for _ in feature_list: # 300 features ['height', 'weights', 'salary']
         keys_to_features[_] = tf.FixedLenFeature([TIME_STEPS], tf.float32)
    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_features)
    t = [tf.manip.reshape(parsed[_], [-1, 1]) for _ in feature_list]
    numeric_tensor = tf.concat(values=t, axis=1)

    x = dict()
    x['numeric'] = numeric_tensor
    y = ...
    w = ...

    return x, y, w

def input_fn(file_pattern, b=BATCH_SIZE):
    """
    :param file_pattern: GCS bucket to read from
    :param b: Batch size, defaults to BATCH_SIZE in hparams.py
    :return: And infinitely iterable data set using tf records of tf.data.Dataset class
    """
    files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(file_pattern=file_pattern)
    d = files.apply(
        tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(
            lambda filename: tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filename),
            cycle_length=4,
            block_length=16,
            buffer_output_elements=16,
            prefetch_input_elements=16,
            sloppy=True))
    d = d.apply(tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(
        map_func=_parse_func, batch_size=b,
        num_parallel_batches=4))
    d = d.cache()
    d = d.repeat()
    d = d.prefetch(1)
    return d
```

Get train data

```
# get files from GCS bucket and load them into dataset
train_data = input_fn(train_directory, b=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Fit the model

```
model.fit(x=train_data.make_one_shot_iterator())
```

I am running it on CloudML so GCS and CloudML should be pretty fast.

---

### CloudML CPU Usage:

As we can see below, the CPU is at 70% and the memory doesn't increase past 10%. So what does the `dataset.cache()` do?

[image]

### GPU metrics in CloudML logs

As seen below, it seems that the GPU is off! Also the memory is at 0mb. Where is the cache stored?

**No processes running on GPU!**

[image]

#### Edit:

It seems that indeed, there are not processes running on GPU. I tried to explicitly state:

```
tf.keras.backend.set_session(tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(
    allow_soft_placement=True,
    log_device_placement=True)))

train_data = input_fn(file_pattern=train_directory, b=BATCH_SIZE)

model = create_model()

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    model.fit(x=train_data.make_one_shot_iterator(),
              epochs=EPOCHS,
              steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
              validation_data=test_data.make_one_shot_iterator(),
              validation_steps=VALIDATION_STEPS)
```

but everything still utilises the CPU!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using a custom `setup.py` file which used a CPU-only Tensorflow version.

I am kicking myself, please install `tensorflow-gpu` instead.

Comment: Wait. If you did use CPU mode, the procedure should be bottlenecked at back-prop stage instead of data I/O. How come you reached 7x faster speed by loading data into memory?

Comment: The 7x was on the default runtime, v1.10 which is preconfigured with GPU. When I specified the 1.12 version of Tensorflow at `setup.py`, it was a CPU only version, where the error occurred. The direct feed of weighs from tf.Dataset is only possible in Tensorflow v.1.12 which is the reason I had to install it. But still, the GPU usage is now at maximum 70%. While the CPU is just at 30% instead of previous 70%. So there is still room for improvement

Comment: If you are using GCP ML, they only support up to TF 1.10 today in their runtime. Which scale tier are you using? You should be using: BASIC_GPU. https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/machine-types